# What is _bittest macro?

Tags: disassembly

Here is an example of the `bt` instruction in a X64 Windows binary:

```
bt      eax, 18h
jnb     short loc_a
lea     rcx, String
call    cs:__imp_wprintf
mov     eax, [rbx+40h]
```

In pseudocode:

```
if ( _bittest(&Mode, 0x18u) )
{
  wprintf(L"String");
  Mode = Properties->Mode;
}
```

What is the `_bittest` macro used in a IF statement? Is it similar with `if(a & b == b)` or something? The code `if(a & b == b)` is used for checking if a flag is present in an OR-ed flag. And from debugging, I found the above assembly code is doing something like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It tests if the *n*th bit is set, returns `true` if set, `false` if not set.

It's basically the same as `if(a & (1 << num_bit))` as the argument is the number of the bit to test rather than the bit (or flag if you will) itself.

Answer (score 2):

`_bittest` is a [compiler intrinsic which maps to the `bt` instruction](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h65k4tze.aspx):

> Generates the `bt` instruction, which examines the bit in position b of
>   address a, and returns the value of that bit.
>
> ```
> unsigned char _bittest(  
>    long const *a,  
>    long b  
> );
> ```

Answer (score 1):

`bt` is an x86 [instruction](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/BT.html) to check if a bit is set in a number/value. It sets `CF` flag as the value of that bit and you can use `jb`/`jnb`/`jc`/`jnc` to check if its 1/0.

```
bt      eax, 18h
```

As already mentioned in @Johann's answer, its equivalent to python

```
CF = (eax & (1 << 0x18)) >> 0x18
```

I have added some code for you to play with it [here](https://gist.github.com/sudhackar/0f566726180ce533a4c8062b2294f021).